# Как прослушивать нажатия клавиш клавиатуры вне приложения?

Tags: java

У меня есть задача: прослушивать нажатия клавиш клавиатуры, вне приложения (в браузере, блокноте или просто на рабочем столе). При помощи чего это можно реализовать? Не нашел никакой информации по этому поводу.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Можно использовать готовую библиотеку. Например [jkeymaster](https://github.com/tulskiy/jkeymaster) или [jnativehook](https://github.com/kwhat/jnativehook).

Answer (score -1):

Думаю, что всё-таки без костылей это решается использованием WinApi (а именно установкой хуков) и, соответственно, писать на C.

UPD: если речь идёт о Windows, конечно